# Time Zone future date - Postman

Tags: javascript, postman-pre-request-script

```js
pm.sendRequest("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome", function (err, res) {
    pm.globals.set("localTimeRome", res.json().datetime);
});
```

How to increase the number of days after reading the date from this api ?
Future date
previous date
future year

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is gonna works for you.

```
const moment = require('moment');

pm.sendRequest("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Rome", function (err, res) {
    var two_days_more = moment.parseZone(res.json().datetime).add(2, 'days');
    pm.globals.set("localTimeRome", two_days_more);
});
```